# Newbie question -- a list of tuples -> list (with workalendar)

Tags: python

```
from workalendar.core import Calendar
from workalendar.registry import registry

CalendarClass = registry.get('US')
calendar = CalendarClass()

# Get the range of years
start_year = 2018
end_year = 2020
all_years = range(start_year, end_year + 1, 1)

# Get the holidays for each of the years
holiday_list = list()

for yearr in all_years:
    holiday_list.append(calendar.holidays(yearr))

holiday_list
```

Truncated output:

```
[[(datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2019, 4, 19), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2019, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')],
[(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2020, 4, 10), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2020, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')],
[(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2021, 4, 2), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2021, 12, 25), 'Christmas Day'),
(datetime.date(2021, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')]]
```

So you can see here that it is three lists of tuples within a list.
Searching online, I kept getting results that would not convert the inner tuples to lists, or still return three lists, or return three-layers of lists, etc.
How can I get a list of lists, where the inner lists contain date and holiday name?

Edit: what the wanted result would look like

```
[[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'New Year'],
[datetime.date(2019, 4, 19), 'Good Friday'],
...
[datetime.date(2020, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day'],
[datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), 'New year'],
...
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 25), 'Christmas Day'],
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day']]
```

Comment: Could you update your question with the wanted result please

Comment: @MariusROBERT done, sorry I should have included that in the first place!

Comment: Please rephrase your title so it summarizes your actual question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way:

```
final_list = []
for inner_list in your_list: final_list += [list(inner_tuple) for inner_tuple in inner_list]
```

Getting this output:

```
[[datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'New year'],
 [datetime.date(2019, 4, 19), 'Good Friday'],
 [datetime.date(2019, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day'],
 [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'New year'],
 [datetime.date(2020, 4, 10), 'Good Friday'],
 [datetime.date(2020, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day'],
 [datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), 'New year'],
 [datetime.date(2021, 4, 2), 'Good Friday'],
 [datetime.date(2021, 12, 25), 'Christmas Day'],
 [datetime.date(2021, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day']]
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert the innermost tuples into lists while preserving their contents, you can iterate through the elements of elements of holiday_list and convert each of them individually:

```
out = [[list(inner_tuple) for inner_tuple in sublist] for sublist in holiday_list]
```

If you want to additionally flatten the list, merge two list comprehensions into one:

```
out = [list(inner_tuple) for sublist in holiday_list for inner_tuple in sublist]
```

In principle, `list(inner_tuple)` converts `inner_tuple` from `tuple` type to `list` type. This occurs `for` every `inner_tuple in sublist`. In the first case, the results are additionally wrapped into a list themselves (inner `[]`). We repeat this for all `sublist in holiday_list` and save it as a list (outer `[]`). Please mind that in the second case the order of `for` statements is reversed.

Comment: Thanks  
How would I make it a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Lets assume the first element is supposed to be a key and the latter a value. If you'd like to have a lot of one-entry dictionaries (not particularly useful), you could do  `{inner_tuple[0]: inner_tuple[1]}` in place of `list(inner_tuple)`. You might be more interested in converting the whole list of tuples into one large dictionary using dict comprehension `{inner_tuple[0]: inner_tuple[1] for sublist in holiday_list for inner_tuple in sublist}` which generates one dictionary. You may read more about comprehensions for example [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comprehensions-in-python/).

Comment: If I haven't made any typo, this should result in a `{datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 'New Year',
datetime.date(2019, 4, 19): 'Good Friday', ...}` dictionary, in which you can access the elements using `datetime.date`-type objects.